# How to convert XML to Dict

Tags: python, xml

I want to find some great solution to convert XML to dict and vice versa in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following recipe should be helpful:

- [XML as Dictionary](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410469-xml-as-dictionary/)

Comment: As it stands, this isn't a very good answer; besides it just linking to a library, it doesn't provide an example of how to use it in the answer itself; and without the link, this answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 10):

[xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) (full disclosure: I wrote it) does exactly that, following this ["standard"](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html). It is [Expat](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html)-based, so it's very fast and doesn't need to load the whole XML tree in memory.

```
>>> print(json.dumps(xmltodict.parse("""
...  <mydocument has="an attribute">
...    <and>
...      <many>elements</many>
...      <many>more elements</many>
...    </and>
...    <plus a="complex">
...      element as well
...    </plus>
...  </mydocument>
...  """), indent=4))
{
    "mydocument": {
        "@has": "an attribute", 
        "and": {
            "many": [
                "elements", 
                "more elements"
            ]
        }, 
        "plus": {
            "@a": "complex", 
            "#text": "element as well"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it stands, this isn't a very good answer; besides it just linking to a library, it doesn't provide an example of how to use it in the answer itself; and without the link, this answer becomes useless.

Comment: Martin, can you please provide a streaming example for xmltodict usage? A simple working example would be great. I have huge XML files that don't fit in RAM, so a streaming example would be great. The one in documentation is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

When converting between XML and Python dictionaries, there are some interesting corner cases that make this non-trivial (attributes? lists? anonymous lists?  single entry lists?  content eval?):
tale a look at this document from the PicklingTools distribution: [XML to Dict conversions](http://www.picklingtools.com/html/xmldoc.html): http://www.picklingtools.com

The docs discuss how to do this, but here's a simple example. 
In a file named ‘example.xml’, we will put the following XML:

```
<top>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2.2</b>
  <c>three</c>
</top>
```

To process this file and turn it into a dictionary:

```
>>> from xmlloader import *
>>> example = file('example.xml', 'r')
>>> xl = StreamXMLLoader(example, 0)  # 0 = All defaults on options
>>> result = xl.expectXML()
>>> print result
{'top': {'a': '1', 'c': 'three', 'b': '2.2'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest taking a look at [declxml](http://declxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to see if it fits your use case (full disclosure: I am the author). With declxml, you create objects called *processors* which declaratively define the structure of your XML document. Processors are used to both parse and serialize between XML and Python values including objects, dictionaries, and namedtuples.

```
import declxml as xml

some_xml = """
<mydocument has="an attribute">
  <and>
    <many>elements</many>
    <many>more elements</many>
  </and>
  <plus a="complex">
    element as well
  </plus>
</mydocument>
"""

processor = xml.dictionary('mydocument', [
    xml.string('.', attribute='has'),
    xml.array(xml.string('many'), nested='and'),
    xml.dictionary('plus', [
        xml.string('.', attribute='a'),
        xml.string('.', alias='plus')
    ])
])

xml.parse_from_string(processor, some_xml)
```

Which produces the following output

```
{'has': 'an attribute',
 'and': ['elements', 'more elements'],
 'plus': {'a': 'complex', 'plus': 'element as well'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `xmltodict` lib. The following snippet works nicely:

```
import xmltodict
with open(file) as fd:
xml = fd.read()
xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way would be roll your own to suit your needs. Get [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), read up on the docs and you should be good to go. In case you have doubts, come right back :)